# Change button state

Tags: jquery, fade

I have the following code which lets me click on one of the button images and have the content inside the div fade in.  This all works great but what I am trying to achieve is to change the state of the button depending on which one is clicked....

http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/2/

### HTML

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
 $(".link").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
      });

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".link")[0].click(); 
    });
```

### CSS

```
.content-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you want the button state to change to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/2/)

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
      $(".link img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png");
      $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png");
});
```

I changed your click function, please see code above. Just polish it :)

Comment: Actually on reflection, is there a way to have a different image assigned to each link?  Would that be done in the HTML instead?

Comment: You have many options actually. You can assign different classes to different links, you can assign the img links to variables.

You can also implement using divs with background and onclick, and assign classes accordingly. (like clickedDiv for example)

Comment: Is this question still open? :D